# Unexpected response code 403 for https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox

Tags: android, api, rest, linkedin-api

I'm using **LinkedIn Android SDK** to **send invitations**. I've configured the SDK to my android project(as a module) by following their documentations. While I'm trying to executing a REST API like

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

with some valid JSON request it works fine, but when i try to call

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox

they return **Access to sending invitation denied** errorCode **0**. Now I'm trying to look for valid linkedin invitation api.

Can any one please tell me, **is my trying api correct to send invitation or not?** If not please advise me the correct one and the procedure to implement.

Comment: Where is your trying api? You only posted an url. That url gives a 401.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps . I've got a [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) it says that linked in changed their apis in 2015, for invitation api I need to configure my account with LinkedIn Partner.

Comment: Invitation API is no longer available to the general public.  If you have permission to use the API still, you should seek help from LinkedIn directly via your designated Partner Engineering rep, rather than in a public forum like this.